# bash, find, exec and echo

Tags: bash, for-loop, command-line, find

```
find . \
  -name 'user_prefs' \
  -exec echo "whitelist_from basheer@hydrofitgroup.com" >> {} \;'
```

I would like to add the line `whitelist_from basheer@hydrofitgroup.com` to all files that are found by `find`, but my command does not work.
It just creates the file '{}'.

Shoud i use the `for` command?

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to escape the '>>', for example like this:

```
find . -name 'user_prefs' -exec sh -c 'echo "whitelist_from basheer@hydrofitgroup.com" >> {}' \;
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I wouldn't exactly call it "escaping".

Answer (score 5):

As said already, using xargs is encouraged, but you can also avoid executing sh many times by:

```
find . -name 'user_prefs' | while read filename; do echo "whitelist_from basheer@hydrofitgroup.com" >>"$filename"; done
```

Comment: This is quite a bit faster than the `xargs` version.